# Using Kimono APIs: How to create one-to-many relationships / nested lists?

Tags: web-crawler

I'm working on creating a Kimono API that crawls a number of pages on www.builtwith.com (a site that lists what software was used to create a website).

I'm quite new at Kimono, so I apologize if this is a silly question.

So for each page I'm crawling on builtwith.com, I'd like to get a nested list with a one-many-many relationship. For example, when browsing www.builtwith.com/oracle.com and www.builtwith.com/google.com I'd like to get something like {{name: Oracle, {webserver: a,b,c}, {javascript libraries: x,y,z},...},{name:Google,....}}.

It seems that Kimono doesn't allow this kind of relationship and makes multiple Collections for this data - see the JSON of my API below. Is there any way that I could format Kimono to have this data as a nested list? Or should I use a different type of webcrawling? I could use BeautifulSoup but think it'd probably be more difficult.

Thanks for your help.

```
{
  "name": "Builtwith3",
  "count": 60,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 2,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "lastsuccess": "Fri Jan 02 2015 05:02:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Fri Jan 02 2015 05:02:08 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "title": "ORACLE.COM"
      },
      {
        "title": "GOOGLE.COM"
      }
    ],
    "collection2": [
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/Web-Server/Oracle-Application-Server",
          "text": "Oracle Application Server"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/ns/UltraDNS-neustar",
          "text": "UltraDNS neustar"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mx/SPF",
          "text": "SPF"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/ssl/Symantec-VeriSign",
          "text": "Symantec VeriSign"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/hosting/Akamai-Hosted",
          "text": "Akamai Hosted"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cms/SiteStudio",
          "text": "SiteStudio"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/J2EE",
          "text": "J2EE"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/Oracle-Dynamic-Monitoring-Service",
          "text": "Oracle Dynamic Monitoring Service"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/analytics/Omniture-SiteCatalyst",
          "text": "Omniture SiteCatalyst"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/analytics/Eloqua",
          "text": "Eloqua"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery",
          "text": "jQuery"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/Modernizr",
          "text": "Modernizr"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/media/Brightcove",
          "text": "Brightcove"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mobile/Viewport-Meta",
          "text": "Viewport Meta"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cdn/Akamai",
          "text": "Akamai"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/HTML5-DocType",
          "text": "HTML5 DocType"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Javascript",
          "text": "Javascript"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Cascading-Style-Sheets",
          "text": "Cascading Style Sheets"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Meta-Description",
          "text": "Meta Description"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Meta-Keywords",
          "text": "Meta Keywords"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Meta-Robot",
          "text": "Meta Robot"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/X-Frame-Options",
          "text": "X-Frame-Options"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/encoding/UTF-8",
          "text": "UTF-8"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/css/Min-Width",
          "text": "Min Width"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/css/Max-Width",
          "text": "Max Width"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cdns/Akamai-Edge",
          "text": "Akamai Edge"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/Web-Server/Apache",
          "text": "Apache"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/ns/Google-DNS",
          "text": "Google DNS"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/ssl/Google-SSL",
          "text": "Google SSL"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mx/DMARC",
          "text": "DMARC"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mx/SPF",
          "text": "SPF"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mx/Google-Apps-for-Business",
          "text": "Google Apps for Business"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/hosting/Google",
          "text": "Google"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cms/dotCMS",
          "text": "dotCMS"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cms/WebBaker",
          "text": "WebBaker"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/J2EE",
          "text": "J2EE"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/PHP",
          "text": "PHP"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/Adobe-ColdFusion",
          "text": "Adobe ColdFusion"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/Perl",
          "text": "Perl"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/analytics/Fireblade",
          "text": "Fireblade"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/Google-API",
          "text": "Google API"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/cdn/GStatic-Google-Static-Content",
          "text": "GStatic Google Static Content"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/mapping/Google-Maps",
          "text": "Google Maps"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/widgets/Google-Plus-One-Platform",
          "text": "Google Plus One Platform"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/X-Frame-Options",
          "text": "X-Frame-Options"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/P3P-Policy",
          "text": "P3P Policy"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Javascript",
          "text": "Javascript"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/X-XSS-Protection",
          "text": "X-XSS-Protection"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/HTML5-DocType",
          "text": "HTML5 DocType"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Canonical-Content-Tag",
          "text": "Canonical Content Tag"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/WAI-ARIA",
          "text": "WAI-ARIA"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/encoding/UTF-8",
          "text": "UTF-8"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/Server/Alternate-Protocol",
          "text": "Alternate Protocol"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/Server/QUIC",
          "text": "QUIC"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/Server/IPv6",
          "text": "IPv6"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/css/Device-Pixel-Ratio",
          "text": "Device Pixel Ratio"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/css/Min-Width",
          "text": "Min Width"
        }
      },
      {
        "curate": {
          "href": "http://trends.builtwith.com/css/Resolution",
          "text": "Resolution"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```